# Are there any variable temperature electric kettle which boil water before letting temperature drop to the desired temperature?

Tags: tea, kettle

I am a green tea enthusiast so I'm looking for a variable temperature electric kettle but since the water in my home is not very clean I don't want to buy one which just heats the water to a given temperature without boiling it first.

Are there any electric kettles which can bring water to a boiling temperature and let it cool until, say 80 degrees Celsius and then make a sound indicating the water is ready?

Comment: To purify water, you should boil it for a minute.  Most electric boilers I see switch off as soon as the water boils.  So this device should not only not switch off completely, but should also not switch from full power until a minute after boiling.

Comment: related (but doesn't ask about boiling) : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/86220/67

Comment: @Juhasz if the quality of water is so bad that one needs to boil for 1 minute, I wouldn't consider using it at all, and go for bottled water.

Answer (score 2):

There are some appliances that do what you're asking for, but they're not exactly kettles.  They have a reservoir of water that gets heated, and then they hold that temperature, and they have a button to dispense hot water as needed.  Most have an option to boil the water first.

As best I can tell from looking at them on amazon, they're labeled as "Water boiler and heater", but you might also try "hot water dispenser"

They're rather useful if you drink a lot of tea through the day ... you can fill them up in the morning, and then you'll have hot water at your preferred temperature when you're ready for your next cup.